# how do i set the below values for different device resolutions?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, set

how do i set the below values for different device resolutions? 
my code is as follows:

```
d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),GameManager.getInstance().getBitmap());
d.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
mProfileName.setCompoundDrawables(d,null,null,null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it programatically, do in following way:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

switch (displaymetrics.densityDpi) {

case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:

    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:

    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:

    break;  
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:

    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:

    break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:

    break;

}
```